# Left adjoint for forgetful functor

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

I am aware that forgetful functors usually have a left adjoint, but I'm more interested in developing my technique.

Let $\mbox{Cat}$ be the category of small categories and $\mbox{Set}$ the category of sets.

> Show that the forgetful functor $U:\mbox{Cat}\to \mbox{Set}$ has a left adjoint.

We need a functor $F:\mbox{Set} \to\mbox{Cat}$ such that we have an adjunction with $F$ as left and $U$ as right adjoint.

An adjunction is determined by finding an assignment $F_0 (X) \in \mbox{Cat}_0, X\in\mbox{Set}_0,$ and for every $X\in \mbox{Set}_0$ a universal morphism
$$\eta _A : A\to U(F_0(X)) $$
from object $X$ to functor $U$. More precisely, this universal morphism is an (the) initial object of the category $(X\downarrow U)$, where
$$(X\downarrow U) _0 = \left\lbrace (h,\mathcal C) \mid \mathcal C \in \mbox{Cat}_0 \ \&\ h : X \to \mathcal C_0 \right\rbrace $$
and a morphism $(h,\mathcal C) \to (k,\mathcal D)$ is a functor $f :\mathcal C\to \mathcal D$ such that 
$$ (U(f)h)(x) = k(x),\quad x\in X. $$

For a fixed set $X$ the initial object is surely something that involves the identity map on $X$. But there's a problem. We must have a (small) category whose set of objects is $X$. Denote this as $\mathcal C^X$. The universal morphism would be $\mbox{id}_X : X\to \mathcal C_0^X = X$.

- **Question**. How do we pick category $\mathcal C^X$?

Once we have that sorted we can define $F :\mbox{Set} \to \mbox{Cat}$ s.t $F(X) = F_0(X)$ and for a map $v : X\to Y$ the morphism (functor) $F(v) : \mathcal C_X\to\mathcal C_Y$ would have to satisfy
$$U(F(v)) \eta _X = \eta _Y v \quad \mbox{i.e in this case}\quad (UF)(v) = v $$

While I am aware of something like constructing a vector space from a (non-empty) set (freeness), I don't know what this would mean for small categories. How to make progress?

Comment: Re your first sentence: Not all forgetful functors have left adjoints, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6376/why-forgetful-functors-usually-have-left-adjoint

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen thanks for the remark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left adjoint to $U$ is the "discrete category functor" $F=D$, which sends a set $X$ to the discrete category $D(X)=D_X$ with the set $X$ as the set of objects, and a mapping $f\colon X\to Y$ to the functor $D(f)=D_f\colon D_X\to D_Y$ between discrete categories, such that $f$ is the mapping on objects of $D_f$. It is obvious that $D\colon\mathbf{Set}\to\mathbf{Cat}$ is indeed a functor. Now the unit mapping of adjunction $(D,U)$ is simply an identity mapping $id(X)\colon X\to U(D_X)$.

Comment: Is there a way to cook up this left adjoint without knowing a priori what it is? The question might be stupid, though, I could similarly ask how we can give (nontrivial) morphisms between arbitrary groups or what not.

Comment: @AlvinLepik There are some ways to construct free objects in a very general situation (e.g. via proof of the Freyd's theorem), but I guess they are too difficult seeing our aim is to construct an adjoint to some reasonable functor as above.

Comment: @AlvinLepik Another way is to look at the isomorphism $\hom(F(X),C)\cong hom(X,U(C))$ and recall that functors from discrete categories correspond to mappings between sets of objects.

Comment: @AlvinLepik But personally I think that constructing a left adjoint (in such simple cases) is like a game, where you should find the easiest (and the most natural) way to construct objects of a one category by objects of another.